# EF Linq Select and Update or vise versa in one step

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the situation that I have multiple async windows services.
All are working with one table "Jobs". Let's say with two columns: "Id" and "Loaded"

In this table are 50 jobs.
What I want now is that this services grap every time only 10 jobs and work on them.

But it is really important that a job will not be processed twice.
The services grap only jobs where "Loaded" is null.

And if now "Service A" comes and load the first 10 jobs where "Loaded" is null what maybe take 5 sec.
And within this 5 sec. "Service B" comes and also load 10 jobs, this jobs will be the same. (DANGER!)

What I want to do now, to avoid double processed jobs, is to load the 10 jobs and update them ("Loaded" to DateTime.UtcNow) in one statement or update the them and load the affected in one statement.

But I don't know if this is possible.
Can someone help me?

Kind regards

Comment: Easiest solution would be to "tell" your windows services which jobs to take, for example by adding an additional column to your table representing a virtual id of each win service, then each service will only take those jobs having its own id.

Comment: That's not practicable, because theoreticaly it could be the same service, because like I said they are async.
Second reason is, I want to learn something ;)

Comment: That's not practicable, because theoreticaly it could be the same service, because like I said they are async.
If "Service A" async grap 10 jobs with it's id and this takes 5 sec. and then within this 5 sec. "Service A" async graps again 10 jobs with it's id, the 10 jobs are also the same.
Second reason is, I want to learn something ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do something like this

```
   list.Where(j => j.Loaded == null).Take(10).AsEnumerable()
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    x.Loaded = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return x;
                })
                .ToList().ForEach(j => //proccess job here);
```

Comment: Unfortunately not: Syntax Error "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

Comment: No, because Loaded is a DateTime column

Comment: Now it is like before, only different formatted.
I don't think that this is right way. (I would wish it would be!)

Comment: Still I get the Syntax Error "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree."

Comment: The problem is, that you do Linq2Objects and not Linq2Sql!

Comment: in linqToSql you should save data before `return x`

Comment: This works, but the question is, does this now solve my problem, because the .AsEnumerable() function loads the data (What takes let's say 5 sec.) and after that, the jobs will be updated. So, this are again two seperate sql steps and not one, correct?!

Comment: I suppose yes, I'm sorry if my answer doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem of concurrent database access. Your purpose is to update each job that was read with a flag so that it is not processed a second time. Two ideas come to mind :

- **Exclusive database access** You will only allow one windows service to read and update the records it read at one time. This will assure that no job is processed twice.
- **Read all the items** Read all the available jobs every time, then distribute them to each windows service. You'll have to implement some form of data sharing between the application that reads the jobs and the windows services. This idea allows you to have more control over what job each service processes.

Comment: So, there is no possibility with a TransactionScope or something?

Comment: Those are only the ideas I've come up with, of course there may be more, TransactionScope is one of them :)